# my is my setMyToken state function not setting

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a variable and setter for useState but when I use the setter it doesn't appear to be working...

Code

```
const [myToken, setMyToken] = useState('');

await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(async(result) => {
            console.log("My Pre Token", result);
            await setMyToken(result);
            console.log("My Token Value: ", myToken);
        });
```

Results... (my console logs showing the before and after...

```
My Pre Token "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkRFVi10ZXN0IEFnZW50IiwiZW1haWwiOiJUZXN0QWdlbnRAcmVkc2h1dHRlcm1lZGlhLmNvbSIsIm5hbWVpZCI6IjciLCJncm91cHNpZCI6ImFhZDBkNGNjLTJhMjgtNDc2Ny04YjZmLWE1MzAxYTMwNWQ2MiIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL2xvY2FsaXR5IjoiMSIsIm5iZiI6MTU5MzEwNzIyMiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzNzEyMDIyLCJpYXQiOjE1OTMxMDcyMjJ9.wtiQjtMuOpmjkMwGkDPQ_SFdNURM65HKfdqbMu3KbK0"
My Token Value:
```

You can see from my output, once I use setMyToken, the value it blank...???

Am I just doing something weird or dumb....

Thanks,

Comment: You can't await a state update. It does not return a promise. You will be able to use the updated `myToken` on the next render, either in the function body or within an effect.

Comment: I took the await off and such, but its still doing the same thing.  Not updating the myToken variable.

Comment: Not updating your variable or not updating your variable *right away*? `myToken` is a `const`. A `const` *cannot* be changed. React state works by creating the `myToken` variable with the updated value on the *next* render. It will not and cannot be updated on the current render cycle.

Comment: Remember - a functional component is just that: a function. Every time it gets rendered that function is called again. This means every variable defined within the function is not the same as before, but a new/re-created variable. `useState` is helpful because it lets you hold on to values from one function call to the next. But the way it works is not by updating the variable in the current function call (`myToken` = 'new value'), but by creating `myToken` with the new value *next* time its called.

Answer (score 0):

`setMyToken` does not return a promise. Instead you can use `useEffect` to log the output:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(myToken), [myToken])
```

Every time `myToken` gets updated the closure inside of the `useEffect` hook will be called.

I think it's misleading to say state updates are asynchronous since that's not technically true (react just updates a different instance of the myToken data instead of the one thats returned from `useState`); But this does mean that you will only get the "new" version of myToken when react runs the function component again.